# How can I make the window of my MAUI app fixed, so not resizable or set a minimum height/width?

Tags: c#, .net, maui, winui-3

How can I set the size of the window in my MAUI Windows application to be fixed? So the user can not resize the window.
Or how is it possible to set a minimum height or width to the window?

Comment: I believe I heard, that this is a feature that will come in the .Net 7 Release. Maybe this link to a discussion thread on GitHub will help you. https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/2370 (HELP How to specify a fixed size for the application window? (.NET MAUI Blazor WinUI))

Answer (score 3):

you can set `OverlappedPresenter.IsResizable` [Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.windowing.overlappedpresenter.isresizable?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1#microsoft-ui-windowing-overlappedpresenter-isresizable) to false using handler api:

```
public App()
{
        InitializeComponent();
#if WINDOWS
        SetWinNoResizable();
#endif
...
}

    public void SetWinNoResizable()
    {
        Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.WindowHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(IWindow),
                                                                    (handler, view) =>
        {
#if WINDOWS
            var nativeWindow = handler.PlatformView;
            IntPtr windowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(nativeWindow);
            WindowId WindowId = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(windowHandle);
            AppWindow appWindow = AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(WindowId);
            var presenter = appWindow.Presenter as OverlappedPresenter;
            presenter.IsResizable = false;
#endif
        });
    }
```